# MySQL Concatenate last item by dot

Tags: mysql, concatenation

i have table Orders

i want to

```
select (OrderName) Values Concatenated by (dash) While last OrderName Concatenated by (Dot)
```

i used the following : `SELECT CONCAT(OrderName , ' - ') AS 'Name' FROM Orders`

Example :

```
order1 - order2 - order3 .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [**GROUP_CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

```
 SELECT CONCAT ( SUBSTRING(`Name`, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(`Name`) - 2),
                 ' . ') as `Name`
 FROM (
           SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(OrderName, ' - ') AS `Name`
           FROM Orders
      ) T
```

Comment: thanks, but the output will be order1 - order2 - order3 - . how can i remove the dash before the dot in last order